# Is $T_{(r,0)}(TM)\cong T_rM$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Where(r,0)$\in T_rM$, $M$ is an manifold.Is $T_{(r,0)}(TM)\cong T_rM$?

Comment: $T(TM) \cong p^*(TM)\oplus p^*(TM)$, where $p:TM \to M$ is the projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dimension of the tangent space is the double of the dimension of the manifold
$dimT_{(r,0)}TM=2dimT_rM$

Comment: Don't ask followup questions in the comments. Just ask a new question.